Set Custom Metatag Title for Products? Taxonomy Term or Vocabulary + Product title - Drupal Commerce
I am using Drupal 10.3 and Drupal Commerce 2.39.
I want to customize the title of a product.
What I need: The page title should be "Taxonomy Vocabulary + Product Title."
I think there is no token available. When I try to browse the available tokens for products, I cannot find any custom field tokens. Am I missing something?
So, how can I achieve setting the title to "Vocabulary + Product Name"?
Alternatively, I am fine with "Taxonomy Term + Product Name."

OK! I am one step closer. I can see now product tokens.
You need to add a metatag field on your producttype.
I can choose then categorys but not the vocabulary name. Any ideas?
